# Using Wordpress ios editor(written in objective-c) in swift project

Tags: ios, swift, wordpress

I'm trying to use [Wordpress-iOS-Editor](https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-Editor-iOS) (written in obj-c) in my SWIFT project. I've managed to install the Wordpress-iOS-Editor Pods and I made a bridge file to connect it with swift project and now I can call any method or function from the Pods in my swift project.

The problem is HOW TO IMPLEMENT the editor in my swift project with the use of Wordpress-iOS-Editor Pods (library) that I already added. (I don't know which methods and how should I use them.)

[image: Project Structure]

Answer (score 0):

In Podfile:

```
use_frameworks!
```

In source:

```
import WordPressEditor
```